# Some field values are erased on new node creation (D7)

Tags: nodes

It is a strange problem.

I noticed that some field values were mysteriously resetted to the default value.

Using Devel I tracked down the problem : the field values of some nodes are erased and replaced with default value when new nodes of the same content type are created.

In this case, the nodes are created programmatically through AJAX with a custom module. It often happens that the jquery event fires multiple times on a single click, which causes 2 to 5 nodes to be created almost instantly. Could it be that the extra nodes created would replace existing ones?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Without to see the code of the custom module is not possible to give a sure answer. Yes, it is possible it happens as you to described.

Comment: Ok I think this is more a jquery problem than a drupal problem.

The problem seems to be that multiple nodes are created at the same time with the same nid.

When I update a field, Drupal sees that the nid is already taken (by the duplicate node) and saves the updated node to new nid. And in the process the content saved on the initial nid is lost. Or something like that. So I will need to prevent the event from firing multiple times on one click.

Comment: When Drupal updates a node, it doesn't change the node ID; when it creates a new node, it doesn't use the node ID. There is something wrong in the code; without seeing it, it is not possible to say what is wrong.

Comment: Any answer needs to be written as answer, not mixed with the question. If you cannot yet write an answer, you need to wait until you are allowed.